# IDE Fatal Errors - Exception in plugin Gradle

Tags: android-studio

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling android studio but I keep getting this error.

> Blockquote

java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 22: distributionUrl=https/://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip\gradle.properties
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:182)
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:92)
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:229)
at java.base/java.nio.file.Path.of(Path.java:147)
at java.base/java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:69)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.util.GradlePropertiesUtil.getGradleServiceDirectoryPath(GradlePropertiesUtil.kt:41)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.util.GradlePropertiesUtil.getPossiblePropertiesFiles(GradlePropertiesUtil.kt:31)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.util.GradlePropertiesUtil.getGradleProperties(GradlePropertiesUtil.kt:22)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.util.GradleJvmResolutionUtil.canUseGradleJavaHomeJdk(GradleJvmResolutionUtil.kt:118)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.util.GradleJvmResolutionUtil.setupGradleJvm(GradleJvmResolutionUtil.kt:37)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.importing.GradleProjectImporter.configureNewProject(GradleProjectImporter.java:242)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.importing.GradleProjectImporter.createProject(GradleProjectImporter.java:221)
at com.android.tools.idea.npw.model.NewProjectModel$multiTemplateRenderer$1.invoke(NewProjectModel.kt:110)
at com.android.tools.idea.npw.model.NewProjectModel$multiTemplateRenderer$1.invoke(NewProjectModel.kt:93)
at com.android.tools.idea.npw.model.MultiTemplateRenderer.countDown(MultiTemplateRenderer.kt:123)
at com.android.tools.idea.npw.model.MultiTemplateRenderer.skipRender(MultiTemplateRenderer.kt:111)
at com.android.tools.idea.npw.model.RenderTemplateModel.handleSkipped(RenderTemplateModel.kt:119)
at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.model.ModelWizard.handleFinished(ModelWizard.java:417)
at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.model.ModelWizard.goForward(ModelWizard.java:339)
at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.model.ModelWizardDialog$FinishAction.doAction(ModelWizardDialog.java:350)
at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper$DialogWrapperAction.actionPerformed(DialogWrapper.java:1834)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:270)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6654)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3345)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6419)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5029)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4861)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2773)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4861)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:778)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:727)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:751)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:749)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:748)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:971)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchMouseEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:906)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:838)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$null$8(IdeEventQueue.java:452)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:744)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$9(IdeEventQueue.java:451)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:808)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:505)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:190)
at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:235)
at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1063)
at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl$MyDialog.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:711)
at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:438)
at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.doShow(DialogWrapper.java:1700)
at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.show(DialogWrapper.java:1659)
at com.android.tools.idea.actions.AndroidNewProjectAction.actionPerformed(AndroidNewProjectAction.kt:49)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:282)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.invokeAction(ActionUtil.java:446)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.invokeAction(ActionUtil.java:431)
at com.intellij.ui.components.labels.ActionLink$1.linkSelected(ActionLink.java:47)
at com.intellij.ui.components.labels.LinkLabel.doClick(LinkLabel.java:138)
at com.intellij.ui.components.labels.ActionLink.doClick(ActionLink.java:56)
at com.intellij.ui.components.labels.LinkLabel$MyMouseHandler.mouseReleased(LinkLabel.java:322)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6654)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3345)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6419)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5029)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4861)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2773)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4861)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:778)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:727)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:751)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:749)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:748)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:971)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchMouseEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:906)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:838)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$null$8(IdeEventQueue.java:452)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:744)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$9(IdeEventQueue.java:451)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:808)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:505)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)

> Blockquote

Comment: can you show content of your `gradle-wrapper.properties` file?

Comment: There was some problem with distributionUrl , even after changing it , the problem persisted. So, I restored the default settings . The gradle and plugin incompatibility was resolved automatically.

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with the distributionUrl and plugin version ,

> distributionUrl=https/://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip

So I went to , Configure > Restore Default Settings.

And I no longer get the problem.